# Перебор объектов в массиве

Tags: java, массивы, arraylist, объекты

```
public class Category 
{ 
  private static Integer id; 
  private static String name; 
  public Category(Integer id, String name) 
  {
     this.id = id; 
     this.name = name; 
  } 
  public Integer getId() 
  { 
    return this.id; 
  } 
  public String getName() 
  { 
    return this.name; 
  }
}


    Category[] test = new Category[2];
    test[0] = new Category(1,"Link");
    test[1] = new Category(1,"Sanfe");
    System.out.println(test[0].getName());
    System.out.println(test[1].getName());
```

Вывод:
Sanfe
Sanfe
Что не так делаю, тоже самое если сделать ArrayList

Comment: public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    } этот метод внутри класса Category

Comment: Кажется ты забыл добавить что должно выводить. ну и сам класс  `Category`

Comment: код конструктора `Category`?

Comment: `public class Category {
    private static Integer id;
    private static String name;

    public Category(Integer id, String name) {
        this.id     = id;
        this.name   = name;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
}`

Comment: уберите `static`. Заодно, выясните, что это такое.

Comment: Ну это не мешает выводить Sanfe а так понял учту

Comment: Про 7 символов забыл, спасибо что ткнули носом.

Answer (score 3):

Поля класса, помеченные `static`, существуют в одном экземпляре для всех объектов данного типа. Исправьте на:

```
private Integer id; 
private String name;
```